# prototypical inheritance sharing properties and methods

Tags: javascript

Is this the correct prototypical inheritance? This shares the properties and methods of the base class. 'class' is a syntax sugar. I wonder if it does the exact same thing as I do in this code.

```
    let Animal = function () {
        this.eats = true;
    }

    Animal.prototype.run = function () {
        console.log("Running");
    }

    let Lion = function () {
        // Call the base class constructor
        Animal.call(this);
        this.roar = function () {
            console.log("Roraring");
        }
    }

    // Setup the prototype
    Lion.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

    // It is a good practice to set the constructor back to original
    Lion.prototype.constructor = Lion;

    var lion1 = new Lion();
    lion1.run();
    console.log(lion1.eats);
```

Comment: Yes, that's how you do it..? Did you have a question about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have seen that you are using the pattern exactly as defined in the MDN prototypical inheritance page. Class keyword is a syntactic sugar in js that is correct. There is absolutely nothing you cannot do with using prototypes that you can do with the "class" keyword.